# how to handle back button in my android device

Tags: android

I have a problem with the "back" button that is on my device

in my project there are a few layout and class. Let's call them A, B, C, D.if I run the project starts from the layout "A" and then "B", "C", "D". on my layout position "D" and press the back button found on the device, I would go back to layout "C", and if pressed again will return to "B" and again to the "A".

I really want is if I hit "back" on my device, if I was in the layout "D" then I will remain on the layout of "D". if I was in the layout "C" then I'll stick to layout "C".
what should I add?

Comment: So you basically want to ignore the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity, you can override onBackPressed and do all the handling you want to do in there. The documentation is available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

You'll need to keep state variables to know where you're at and what needs to be displayed next when the user press back...

You can always call `super.onBackPressed()` when you want to just use the default behavior too (finishing the current activity)

Comment: so, i add @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBackPressed();

Comment: In that function you can change what layout you want to display, you can just not do anything if you like. Only if you want to have the same "default" behavior, you should call super.onBackPressed()

Comment: so what should I add that if I wanted to "back" button does not work on my project

Comment: Just do not do anything in that function, leave it empty

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in each activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {                         
        }
        return true;
}
```